# Why do two svg elements move with the same `transition` property behave differently?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, svg, css-transitions

In svg, I add `transition: all 3s linear` to both `<rect>` and `<path>`, and then click a button to make the `<rect>`
and `<path>` repeatedly and simultaneously move the same distance between two positions, but during the movement, why doesn't the relative distance between `<rect>` and `<path>` stay the same?

Browser: Chrome

Demo running with Chrome:

[image: gif for demo]

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("#svg");
const path = svg.querySelector("path");
const rect = svg.querySelector("g");
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

const paths = [
  'M 29 12.6 h 30',
  'M 29 32.6 h 30',
]
const hs = [2, 22];
let i = 0;
btn.onclick = () => {
  path.setAttribute("d", paths[i]);
  rect.setAttribute("transform", `translate(0,${hs[i]})`);
  i ^= 1;
}
```

```css
svg * {
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 -10 50 50">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ff6699" d="M 29 12.6 h 30"></path>
  <g transform="translate(0,2)">
  <rect x="29" y="0" width="30" height="10"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
<br>
<button id="btn">Click quickly and repeatedly</button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "why doesn't the relative distance between <rect> and <path> stay the same"? Are you wondering why the 1px white band between the two elements sometimes goes thinner? That's just antialiasing.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't think it's because of antialiasing, I uploaded a gif showing the effect running with chrome

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** *The following answer only applies to the Firefox behavior, where `transform` is not animated. Chrome shows a different problem, and it seems that was what you asked about.*

`transition` is a CSS property, but you try to animate presentation attributes. That seems to work for `d` (amazingly, in my opinion), but not for `transform`, where there is no transition and the value changes instantaneously.

While the spec tries to give the impression that presentation attributes and CSS properties are freely interchangable, in practice you get some rough edges again and again. I am not going to try to find out if what you tried to do is supposed to work according to spec. In my experience it is just sensible to stay on one side of the fence. So, if you try to animate something with the **CSS** `transition` property, that something should also be written as a **CSS** property.

Instead of `transform="translate(0,2)"`, use `style="transform:translate(0,2px)"` - take care to add the `px` unit.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("#svg");
const path = svg.querySelector("path");
const rect = svg.querySelector("g");
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

const paths = [
  'M 29 12.6 h 30',
  'M 29 32.6 h 30',
]
const hs = [2, 22];
let i = 0;
btn.onclick = () => {
  path.setAttribute("d", paths[i]);
  rect.style.transform = `translate(0,${hs[i]}px)`;
  i ^= 1;
}
```

```css
svg * {
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="200" height="200" viewbox="0 -10 50 50">
  <path fill="none" stroke="#ff6699" d="M 29 12.6 h 30"></path>
  <g style="transform:translate(0,2px)">
  <rect x="29" y="0" width="30" height="10"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
<br>
<button id="btn">Click quickly and repeatedly</button>
```

Comment: I tried your modified demo, the space between rect and path still changes when the button is clicked quickly.

Comment: Only in Chrome. Firefox does not show problems.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to work directly, `transform` is a [presentation attribute](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/styling.html#PresentationAttributes), and presentation attributes ought to be mapped to their CSS counter-parts. https://bugzil.la/878346